# is Shimano GRX ST-RX810-R 11 speed shifter compatible with Shimano XT M8000 Shadow+ Rear Derailleur - 11 Speed - Medium Cage GS

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, shifter, compatibility

is grx ST-RX810-R rear shifter compatible with xt rear derailleur, Shimano XT M8000 Shadow+ Rear Derailleur - 11 Speed - Medium Cage GS

Answer (score 2):

No, Shimano 11 mountain and road cable pull are different. If you want bigger than the 42t that GRX rear derailleurs can do, you're going to either be dropping down a road derailleur with one of the hanger extensions, or using an adapter to a mountain derailleur.

Comment: Speaking of the adaptors (Shimano road shifters to MTB rear derailleurs), I've had good luck with couple of them. I'm not a particularly skillful mechanic & I had them setup and shifting well with reasonable effort.

Comment: You could also use a friction shifter. Maybe not ideal for 11 speed but it works fine on my 9x.